# Parseval's theorem, Energy

Tags: convolution, signal-energy, parseval

I was wondering, how can Parsevals theorem (energy in time domain is equal to the energy in frequency domain) hold for sampling. I take three sampels from a sinc-function. This reduces the energy in time domain, but in the frequency domain the energy gets bigger.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic here. If your signal is discrete you should be using sums, not integrals.  Also, if you truncate the sinc to three samples, the spectrum is not a rectangle anymore.

Comment: Don't post a picture, write [LaTeX](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076) that we can read easily.

Answer (score 1):

Perceval's theorem holds for the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) if you use proper scaling, i.e.

$$X[k] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}} \leftrightarrow  x[n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}} $$

In this case we can show that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |X[k]|^2 $$

It's difficult to see from the paper drawing what exactly you did and which Fourier Transform flavor you were using so I can't really comment in your results. I suggest adding some equations with the specifics.

Comment: yes, I posted a new picture